# Блокировка кнопки без checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

помогите, пожалуйста, как сделать блокировку кнопки "Далее" на JQuery, пока пользователь не поставит галочку на чекбоксе? В этой ситуации, код показываю:

```
    <div class="order_three_confirmation">
        <label class="order_label_checkbox">
          <span class="order_checkbox"></span>
          <input type="checkbox" class="hide" name="personal_data">
          Соглашение о предоставлении персональных данных.
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="order_btns">
        <button class="order_btn order_btn_prev">Назад</button>
        <button class="order_btn order_btn_next">Далее</button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Т.е. кнопка `<button class="order_btn order_btn_next">Далее</button>` должна быть не активна, пока пользователь не нажмет `<input type="checkbox" class="hide" name="personal_data">`

Огромное спасибо заранее.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы сделал вот так:

```js
$(document).on('change', '[name=personal_data]', function() {
    let $btn = $(document).find('.order_btn_next');
    if(this.checked) {
      $btn.prop('disabled', false);
    } else {
      $btn.prop('disabled', true);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="order_three_confirmation">
    <label class="order_label_checkbox">
      <span class="order_checkbox"></span>
      <input type="checkbox" class="hide" name="personal_data">
      Соглашение о предоставлении персональных данных.
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="order_btns">
    <button class="order_btn order_btn_prev">Назад</button>
    <button class="order_btn order_btn_next" disabled>Далее</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое.